flow of data inside the Retinanet model in each epoch
How much of data were supplied to retinanet model_network by giving batch_size, epochs and steps per epochs?
So far, I thought that the steps size was calculated as following:
step_size = (total_number_of_data/batch_size)*epochs

Whereas in keras-retinanet, it takes batch_size, epochs and steps_per_epoch as arguments, which was different from above mentioned case. I have a doubt how the calculations takes place.
